# Why must I write i+1 in the printf() section whilst I write i++ for incrementing?

Tags: c, arrays

Codes in Array, dealing with

```
   printf("\n How many integers? ")
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   printf("\n Enter the %dth value : ", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &x[i];
```

Comment: Because `i++` doesn't return the same value as `i+1` (unlike `++i`) and also because it would increase `i` again, so you would increase it twice in the loop.

Comment: If you use `i++` in `printf()` as well, then for every iteration of loop `i` will be icremented twice

Comment: because the first iteration `i` would be 0 and presumably because you do not approve of the hacker convention of doing 0-based ordinals...

Comment: Because `i+1` passed to  `printf` is not intended to increment `i`.

Comment: Your code is broken: it asks for all elements at once *then* reads them all in.

Comment: @Quentin it's worse: it reads in data for *one* out-of-range element.

Comment: @Quentin then reads *one* in, potentially beyond the end of `x`

Comment: What they are trying to say is that you should use {} after every for loop, and that you should indent your code so that it is readable to yourself and others. Easy to spot the bugs once you have fixed that.

Comment: @Caleth indeed. Fortunately, coffee is on the way.

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance,  Mr. @Blaze & the present fraternity, I'm a beginner at programming, hence the confusion. And I still have it. I have been told it increments the i's value. But if the `i` in printf is outside of the loop, why does it still increment it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i++` evaluates to the current value of `i`, and as a *side effect* increments `i`.  So if you used `i++` in the `printf` statement, you’d wind up incrementing `i` *twice* per loop iteration.  Your output would be

```
Enter the 0th value:
Enter the 2th value:
Enter the 4th value:
```

etc.

You’d wind up writing past the end of your array midway through the loop.

As others have pointed out, though, you have a problem in that your `scanf` call isn’t part of the loop - your code is interpreted as

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
  printf( “\nEnter the %dth value: “, i + 1 );
}
scanf( “%d”, &x[i] );
```

If more than one statement is part of the loop body, then they need to be between the {}:

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
  printf( “\nEnter the %dth value: “, i + 1 );
  scanf( “%d”, &x[i] );
}
```

**EDIT**

From the comments:

> I'd be highly obliged if you could enlighten me on the ***i++ evaluates, and then increments 1.***

The *result* of the expression `i++` is the current value of `i`, and the *side effect* is that `i` is incremented.  Let's suppose you have the following code:

```
i = 1;
x = i++;
```

After those statements are executed, `x` will have the value `1` (the value of `i` before the increment) and `i` will have the value `2`.  It's *roughly* equivalent to writing

```
x = i;
i = i + 1;
```

except that `i` is only evaluated once, and the exact order of when `x` is assigned and when `i` is updated is unspecified.  The compiler *may* generate code that updates `i` *before* assigning the old value of `i` to `x`:

```
mov i, %eax    ;; assign i to a temporary
inc i          ;; increment i
mov %eax, x    ;; assign the temporary to x
```

Of course, it would be more straightforward to generate

```
mov i, x
inc i
```

but there may be a reason to do it the other way around.

What matters is the end result - `x` gets the value of `i` *before* the increment, and `i` is incremented.

`++i` evaluates to `i + 1`, and the *side effect* is to increment `i`.  If you write

```
i = 1;
x = ++i;
```

then after those statements are executed, both `x` and `i` have the value 2.  It's similar to writing

```
x = i + 1;
i = i + 1;
```

with the same caveats as above - the order in which `x` is assigned and `i` is updated is *unspecified*, and it's entirely possible for the compiler to generate code like this:

```
mov i, %eax   ;; assign i to a temporary
inc %eax      ;; increment the temporary
mov %eax, x   ;; assign the temporary to x
inc i         ;; increment i
```

even though something like

```
inc i
mov i, x
```

would be more straightforward.

Again, what matters is that `x` gets the value of `i + 1`, and that `i` is incremented.

> Also, so far(in my journey of learning C), I've seen i++ incrementing only in steps of 1. So, I'm clueless about how it may increment to 2 in this case. And, how is i+1 different to impede that?

Your question title asks why you should use `i+1` instead of `i++` in your print statement.  Let's assume you wrote

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   printf("\n Enter the %dth value : ", i++);
   ...
}
```

If you had written your code like this, then `i` would be updated twice per loop iteration, which is not what you want.  You don't want to *modify* `i` in the `printf` call.  `i++` (and `++i`, `--i`, and `i--`) all *modify* the value of `i`.  `i+1` doesn't modify the value of `i`.

Comment: Dear Sir @John Bode, I'd be highly obliged if you could enlighten me on the ***i++ evaluates, and then increments 1***. Also, so far(in my journey of learning C), I've seen  i++ incrementing only in steps of 1. So, I'm clueless about how it may increment to 2 in this case. And, how is i+1 different to impede that?

Comment: I extend my sincerest of gratitude to you, Sir, for sparing your valuable time in providing me with this detailed explanation. Understanding the problem better helps/has helped me in keeping my vigor & persistence   toward learning C. So, this is very, very appreciated. Thank you, Mr. @John Bode!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
printf("\n How many integers? ")
scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  printf("\n Enter the %dth value : ", i+1);
  scanf("%d", &x[i]);
}
```

Readability is everything.

Answer (score 0):

Because `i++` is not, not, not, a thousand times not the same as `i + 1`.

- `i + 1` takes `i`'s value and adds 1 to it and gives you the new value.
- `i++`, on the other hand, takes `i`'s new value and adds 1 to it *and stores the new result back into `i`*.  Also it gives you the old value.
- And then there's `++i`, which takes `i`'s new value and adds 1 to it and stores the new result back into `i` and gives you the new value.
- Finally, we have `i = i + 1` and `i += 1`, both of which take `i`'s new value and add 1 to it and store the new result back into `i` and give you the new value, i.e., both of which are more or less equivalent to `++i`.

So if you want to print one more than `i`, but without changing `i`'s value, a call like `printf("Enter the %dth value: ", i+1)` is exactly what you want.

You said you were told that it "increments `i`", but you have to be clear on what you think "increment" means.  Does it mean "take `i`'s value and add 1 to it and give you the result", or does it mean "take `i`'s value and add 1 to it and store the result back in `i`"?  As you can see, those are two very different things.